# C++ class as member of other class, How does one define this?

Tags: c++, object, syntax

Writing the definition for a class which is the member of another class (given code, don't ask me why). Anyways, I get a type 'class' redefinition error, as I am unfamiliar with c++, the nesting of objects, and the qualifier '::'

Here's stack.h

```
    // rest of code above         
    public: // prototypes to be used by the client

   /**  UnderFlow Class
   *    thrown if a pop or top operation would cause the stack to underflow
   */
    class OverFlow
    {
        public:
            /*! @function   OverFlow Constructor
            *   @abstract   constructs the overflow object
            *   @param      string the error message of the overflow exception
            */
            OverFlow(std::string);

            /*! @function   getMessage
            *   @abstract   returns the message containing this exception's error text
            *   @result     string the error message of the overflow exception
            */
            std::string getMessage();

        private:
            std::string message;//error text

    };

    /** UnderFlow Class
    *   thrown if a pop or top operation would cause the stack to underflow
    */
    class UnderFlow
    {
        public:
            /*! @function   UnderFlow Constructor
            *   @abstract   constructs the underflow object
            *   @param      string the error message of the underflow exception
            */
            UnderFlow(std::string);

            /*! @function   getMessage
            *   @abstract   returns the message containing this exception's error text
            *   @result     string the error message of the underflow exception
            */
            std::string getMessage();
    //rest of code below
```

And here's stack.cpp

```
    //rest of code above
    class stack::OverFlow
    {

string message;
OverFlow::OverFlow()
{

}

OverFlow(string errormessage)
{
    OverFlow::message = errormessage;
}

string OverFlow::getMessage()
{
    return message;
}

};
   class stack::UnderFlow
    {
string message;

UnderFlow::UnderFlow()
{

}

UnderFlow::UnderFlow(string errormessage)
{
    message = errormessage;
}

string UnderFlow::getMessage()
{
    return message;
}


};//rest of code below
```

I get the redefinition error on the following lines of code

```
class stack::UnderFlow
class stack::OverFlow
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix, I'm just out of practice...

Comment: I love how a question about the `stack::OverFlow` class is being posted on Stack Overflow

Comment: The irony is palpable, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class definition should appear in the header file, not the C++ file. Remove:

```
class stack::OverFlow
{
```

from the C++ file.

Comment: The definition appears in the header file...? That just doesn't sound right, care to elaborate?

Comment: You have a class definition in both the header and the implementation, thus you get a reimplementation error. Remove the one from the C++ file. Only member functions should be in there, not a class definition.

Comment: Removing the "class stack::OverFlow" line with its corresponding braces caused the following errors:

'OverFlow: is not a class or namespace name'
repeated for each usage of overflow, and underflow

Comment: By the way, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Adding stack:: before each usage fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

currently you wrote

```
//rest of code above
class stack::OverFlow
{

string message;
OverFlow::OverFlow()
{
}
```

in `stack.cpp` file. This is not correct to write class body in cpp file, you should do it in header, so you should remove

```
class stack::OverFlow
    {
```

from source file (`cpp`). And you have this done in header too (and this one is correct), so now you only need to remove mentioned parts and add function's definitions with correct name resolution in `cpp`, like this:

```
stack::OverFlow::OverFlow()  // constructor
{
}

string stack::UnderFlow::getMessage()  // function definition
{
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I combined your advice with that given by David and it seemed to do the trick

Comment: Justin, I am your very fan